# Javascript Button onClick not working in Chrome extension popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

(link to git: https://github.com/Boundarybreaker/NameBlock)

I'm working on a text-replacement extension that can be toggled on and off with a button clicked in the `popup.html`, but it only is happening when I click the icon. (video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_3pLT_KI8V8OHJFUHQ5a1JURkE/view?usp=sharing)

The code for the button reads `<button class="ui fluid red button" onclick=toggleActive() id="toggle">Toggle Active</button>`, and `toggleActive()` is a function in `background.js`, along with a listener `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(toggleActive);`. How would I get the button to work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onclick is a kind of inline scripting, so it's forbidden in popup.

Use `myButton.addEventListener('click',toggleActive);` in your popup.js
Obtain `myButton` in any usual way, by adding an id to its html and using `document.getElementById`, or by `getElementsByClassName, querySelectorAll` or any other ways.

`toggleActive` defined in popup.js can either send message to background.js, where the listener would call background's `toggleActive`, or you can just get background page with `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage` or `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage` (the former is async, the latter is sync, returning window object of background) and call your background `toggleActive` from here, like this:

`var bkg=chrome.extenstion.getBackgroundPage();
bkg.toggleActive();`

That is, if you really need defining your toggleActive in background instead of popup.

Comment: I tried the addEventListener line and it somewhat works. Instead of just clicking the Toggle Active button, it works clicking anywhere on the extension, which is not optimal. I'll see if getBackGround page helps.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake trying to edit the answer as brief as possible. It should be the control you want to click on, not the document itself, that you'd add the listener to. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should do that:

```
<button class="ui fluid red button" onclick="toggleActive()" id="toggle">Toggle Active</button>
```

You forget the parentheses after onclick.