# Google extensions: How to run a function in my javascript file when button is pressed in the popup?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a google extension where I want to change the background-color of youtube.com by pressing a button in my `popup.html` and then running my function.

Here is my code:

The JavaScript file `ms.js`:

```
function color1(){
document.getElementById("body-container").style.backgroundColor="blue";}
```

The HTML `popup.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="ms.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p> TEST </p>
<input type="button" value="blue" id="btn1" onclick="color1"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my `manifest.json` file:

```
{

"name": "my extension test",

"version": "1.0",

"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "pageCapture"
],

"manifest_version": 2,

"description": "Test extension :D",

"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "ikon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
},

"web_accessible_resources": [
"script/ms.js"
],

"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/*"],
      "js": ["ms.js"]
    }
  ]

}
```

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36317641/javascript-button-onclick-not-working-in-chrome-extension-popup?rq=1) if it can help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated

1. Content Scripts(injected through `manifest.json`) is not needed, so we remove `content_scripts` part
2. We decide to use [Programming injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi), the only needed permission is [activeTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab), so we remove `activeTab` and `pageCapture`. If you want your scripts to be executed in background tab(not active tab), then you could replace `activeTab` permission with host permission.
3. [Web Accessible Resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) is supposed to be used when we expect some resources to be used in the context of a web page, content scripts themselves don't need to be whitelisted, so we remove `web_accessible_resources` part
4. JavaScript is executed when it's found in the document, if you include it inside `<head>` tag, the `<body>` is not constructed then you could find the element, so we put that in the bottom of `<body>`
5. [Inline Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution) won't be executed by default, so we move this event binding logic to external scripts.

Take a look at [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript), for such minor feature, you could inject JavaScript code into a page.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "my extension test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Test extension :D",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <p> TEST </p>
    <input type="button" value="blue" id="btn1" />
    <script src="ms.js">

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

ms.js

```
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({"code": 'document.getElementById("body-container").style.backgroundColor = "blue";'});
}, false);
```

Comment: Code dump correcting multiple errors/misconceptions, but no explanation.

Comment: I disagree with replacing `"activeTab"` with a host permission, but at least it's now a valuable answer.

Comment: @Xan, provided more info about activeTab and host permissions.